# error CS1513: } expected in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, compiler-errors

I have a view which is very simple. It contains some C# code.

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Community";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<div id="req1">
  <form>
     <input id="txt1" type="text" name="txt1" />
 </form>
</div>
<div id="btn1">Send</div>
<div id="res1"></div>
@{
    public string GetPassage(string strSearch)
    {
       using (var c = new System.Net.WebClient())
       {
           string url = "http://www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?key=IP&passage=' + strSearch + '&options=include-passage-references=true";
           return c.DownloadString(Server.UrlDecode(url));               
       }
    }
 }
```

I don't know what is wrong. The error message is:

```
Source Error:

Line 117:EndContext("~/Views/Home/Community.cshtml", 236, 9, true);
```

**Update:**

If I moved the code to controller.

```
public ActionResult Community()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "";

    return View();
}

public string GetPassage(string strSearch)
{
    using (var c = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        string url = "http://www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?key=IP&passage=" + strSearch + "&options=include-passage-references=true";
        return c.DownloadString(Server.UrlDecode(url));
    }
}
```

And I want to make a ajax call based on [the example](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/). How is the code in javascript?

Comment: Those are two different files.

Comment: That code doesn't belong in a view, should  be in controller or elsewhere really.

Comment: Maybe it is related to the line where you are building the url. You should be using double quotes instead of single quotes. `' + strSearch + '` should be `" + strSearch + "`.

Comment: @chue, no. Even I remove this line, it is still wrong. I guess it might be in a controller.

Comment: @Love - Perhaps unrelated, but it still looks like a bug to me.

Comment: You are right, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View is not the right place to declare a method. In fact all code that you write in a View between `@{` and `}` is run within the same method (not entirely true, but makes the point). Obviously declaration of a method inside another method is impossible in C#, view engine just does not have enough means to translate it to you literally.

However if you need some utility method on a view - you can create a delegate and call it later:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Community";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<div id="req1">
  <form>
     <input id="txt1" type="text" name="txt1" />
 </form>
</div>
<div id="btn1">Send</div>
<div id="res1"></div>

@{
    Func<string, string> getPassge = strSearch =>
    {
        using (var c = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            string url = "http://www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?key=IP&passage=' + strSearch + '&options=include-passage-references=true";
            return c.DownloadString(Server.UrlDecode(url));
        }
    };
 }
```

Comment: Okay, if I move it to a controller. How it is related with a specific ActionResult?

Comment: @Love, since `GetPassage` returns a plain string, the closest `ActionResult` method is `Content`. However I doubt the very idea of turning this method into action method. It is hard to advice what should be done with this method without knowing scenarios of its use.

Comment: I want to make an ajax call, the sample is at http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/. The example has var url = "/Monitor/Test/ReverseTheString"; I am not sure what is /Monitor then?

Comment: @Love, most likely Monitor is an Area. If you have no areas definedm then you can safely leave it out, having just "/Test/ReverseTheString"

Comment: could you please look at my update? Suppose the controller class is HomeController.cs.

Comment: @Love, the link you have shown gives an excellent example of this JS call. See the section `Call An Action Method That Returns A String But Takes Parameters`